# I'm trying to set up Sitecore website and I get the error bellow.Looked all config files I could find.I created website with SIM tool

Tags: .net, xml, sitecore

I'm trying to set up a Sitecore website and I get the error below. Looked all config files I could find, but did not find any weird characters.

I created a website with SIM tool and followed Sitecore steps.

> [XmlException: Unexpected end of file while parsing CDATA has occurred. Line 
>   13, position 1722.]
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +88
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseCDataOrComment(XmlNodeType type, Int32& outStartPos, Int32& outEndPos) +1106
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseCDataOrComment(XmlNodeType type) +272
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent() +331
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc) +25
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) +134
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename) +146
>   Sitecore.Xml.XmlUtil.LoadXmlFile(String filename) +136
>
> Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.NexusLicenseApi.() +259
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.NexusLicenseApi.GetModuleCount(String name) +138
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.NexusLicenseApi.HasModule(String name) +131
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.XdbSettings.get_HasValidLicense() +22
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.XdbSettings.get_Enabled() +9
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.Initialize.ShowXdbInfo.Process(PipelineArgs args) +228(Object , Object[] ) +71
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469

Comment: Where did you get you license.xml file from? Are you sure it's a valid one?

Comment: I have got licence from sitecore for 2 months trial period.

Comment: This exception clearly states the the xml of the license is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception clearly states that your license file is not valid.

Put a correct license.xml file in the Data folder used by your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marek, it will be very helpful for me.